# How to add up Column B based on whether Column A is a duplicate value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, duplicate, microsoft-excel-2011

I have two columns, one with names and the other filled with '1'. Column A has many duplicates in it - this is intended - what I need is a **formula to add the 1s in Column B if the corresponding values in Column A are duplicates, and output this to Column C**. Column A is sorted in alphabetical order. Here is an example of my data:

```
Col A           Col B   Col C
Abdulia Mussah  1
Abena Achiaa    1
Abena Afiah     1
Abena Afiah     1
Abena Afiah     1
Abena Afiah     1
Abena Afiah     1
Abena Ajalla    1
Abena Asabrah   1
Abena Asabrah   1
```

As you can see there are many duplicates. I need Column C to have an added value of all the 1s where the duplicates are. So for example it the result would look something like this ideally:

```
Col A           Col B   Col C
Abdulia Mussah  1       1
Abena Achiaa    1       1
Abena Afiah     1       5
Abena Afiah     1       5
Abena Afiah     1       5
Abena Afiah     1       5
Abena Afiah     1       5
Abena Ajalla    1       1
Abena Asabrah   1       2
Abena Asabrah   1       2
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For summing you should use [sumif](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/SUMIF-function-5fd078db-e5f8-4726-b08f-74fd0064e7fe?ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ)

```
=sumif(A1:A100,A1,B1:B100)
```

Basically it looks for the second argument (can be reference or manual) in the first range and sums the corresponding second range.

For this one in particular, you could use

```
=sumif($A:A,A1,$B:B)
```

and drag it down column C

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you use

```
=SUMIF($A:A,A2,$B:B)
```

Enter the folmula in A2 in this (and most examples) since it has a column name in A1.

Drag it down column C.